# Best way to check if column returns a null value (from database to .net application)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datatable, null

I have a table with a DateTime column
the column can have NULL values

Now I connect to the database using an ODBC connection and get the value into a DataTable in .net / c#.

I am able to check it for NULL by going

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(table.rows[0][0].ToString())
{
     //Whatever I want to do
}
```

Is String.IsNullOrEmpty the correct way to check for null values.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use [DBNull.Value.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx) on the object without converting it to a string.

Here's an example:

```
   if (! DBNull.Value.Equals(row[fieldName])) 
   {
      //not null
   }
   else
   {
      //null
   }
```

Comment: This looks like the correct way. As it says in the above link 
"The following example calls the DBNull.Value.Equals method to determine whether a database field in a contacts database has a valid value. If it does, the field value is appended to the string output in a label."

Answer (score 12):

Just use **[DataRow.IsNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull.aspx)**. It has overrides accepting a **column index**, a **column name**, or a **DataColumn object** as parameters.

Example using the column index:

```
if (table.rows[0].IsNull(0))
{
    //Whatever I want to do
}
```

And although the function is called `IsNull` it really compares with **`DbNull`** (which is exactly what you need).

---

What if I want to check for DbNull but I don't have a DataRow? Use [Convert.IsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

```
System.Convert.IsDbNull][1](table.rows[0][0]);
```

IIRC, the `(table.rows[0][0] == null)` won't work, as `DbNull.Value != null;`

Answer (score 1):

row.IsNull("column")

Answer (score 0):

If we are using EF and reading the database element in while loop then,

```
   using( var idr = connection, SP.......)
   {
       while(idr.read())
       {
          if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(idr["ColumnNameFromDB"].ToString())
          //do something
       }
   }
```

Comment: string. , not sting.

Answer (score -6):

Just check for

```
if(table.rows[0][0] == null)
{
     //Whatever I want to do
}
```

or you could

```
if(t.Rows[0].IsNull(0))
{
     //Whatever I want to do
}
```

Comment: table.rows[0][0] == null fails thats why I was using the .ToString() and then checking using String.IsNullOrEmpty

Comment: the IsNull method would work, but you can't compare null to null directly;  null == null is false. At best, you8 have to compare to DBNull.Value

Comment: @Val: No. null == null is true.

Comment: @emilsteen D'oh, of course you're right. Nine years on, I can't remember why I was shooting from the hip :-(