# Getting DBNull exception

Tags: c#, .net

Very strange while reading database values I am checking if a column is dbnull or not but while checking it I get dbnull exception,

```
if(!DBNull.Value.Equals(DataBaseTableRow.ColumnName))
               myString = DataBaseTableRow.ColumnName;
```

Error:

> he value for column 'ColumnName' in table 'Table' is DBNull. --->
>   Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017533/best-way-to-check-if-column-returns-a-null-value-from-database-to-net-applicat

Comment: the point is : Are you sure the error occur in that part of the code ? And is "DataVase" more than a copy-paste typo ? ;-)

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQL Server.

Comment: I am used to syntax like this DataBaseTableRow[ColumnName]

Comment: Stick a breakpoint on myString and see the value of ColumuName. while you are in Debug mode check if !DBNull.Value.Equals(DataBaseTableRow.ColumnName) is true of false.

Comment: if your code fails at runtime (and not at compile time) `DataBaseTableRow` is likely a DataColumn. Unlike `DataRow`, `DataColumn` has a `ColumnName` property that returns the... name of the column as a `string`. ColumnName will never be Equal to `DBNull`, so your if as it is does not make sense to me.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella - That's what a lot of people seem confused about. But if ColumnName will never be equal to `DBNull`, then that exception should also never be thrown. I have the feeling something is missing here.

Comment: @user13814, is this a typed dataset you are working with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by finding a method provided by dataset, DataBaseTableRow.IsColumnNameNull(); whereas ColumnName is the original name of column, it is only available to columns that are not null able in database.

```
if(!DataBaseTableRow.ISColumnNameNull())
               myString = DataBaseTableRow.ColumnName;
```

Comment: So you have worked with a typed dataset. You would have got an answer faster if you had stated this in your question.

Comment: @Heslacher DataBaseTableRow.ColumnName only works with typed dataset, I had enough of negative comments today, please let me go now, thanks