# Nullable DateTime from SQL database into Datatable using generics and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, generics, null

I have the following problem when reading a datetime field from sql into a datatable.
The query works fine, however when I get to the foreach loop it complains about a null value in the datetime fields.

I have a class defined as:

```
public class trading_book_product_IRS        
    {
        public DataTable dt_IRS { get; set; }

        public string account_deal_position_id { get; set; }
        public DateTime schedule_start_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime schedule_end_date { get; set; }
        public string repricing_type { get; set; }
        public string coupon_type { get; set; }
        public string reference_curve { get; set; }
        public string reference_curve_point { get; set; }
        public decimal interest_rate { get; set; }
        public decimal interest_rate_spread { get; set; }        
}
```

I create my datatable using the following, because I do it in this way, I cannot use `DateTime`?

```
public static DataTable CreateDataTable(Type animaltype)
    {
        DataTable return_Datatable = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in animaltype.GetProperties())
        {
            if (!info.Name.StartsWith("dt_"))
            {
                return_Datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, info.PropertyType));
            }
        }
        return return_Datatable;
    }
```

I then do my query and expect to write results, however I cannot deal with the DateTime being null.  What I'm attempting to do is:  if the datetime is null, make the date 99990101.  The problem lies in the schedule_end_date and schedule_start_date fields.

```
 var query =
            from result in t_sdi_trading_book_product_interest_repricing_schedule_hsbc.AsEnumerable()
            where result.sdi_control_id == sdi_id
            && accountDealIDs.Contains(result.account_deal_position_id)
            select new trading_book_product_IRS()
            {
                account_deal_position_id = result.account_deal_position_id,
                coupon_type = result.coupon_type,
                interest_rate = result.interest_rate,
                interest_rate_spread = result.interest_rate_spread,
                reference_curve = result.reference_curve,
                reference_curve_point = result.reference_curve_point,
                repricing_type = result.repricing_type,
                schedule_end_date = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.schedule_end_date.ToString()) ? result.schedule_end_date : DateTime.Parse("99990101"),
                schedule_start_date = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.schedule_start_date.ToString()) ? result.schedule_start_date : DateTime.Parse("99990101"),
            };

        foreach (var results in query)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo result in results.GetType().GetProperties())
            {

                string name = result.Name;

                foreach (PropertyInfo info in used.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    if ((result.Name == info.Name) && (!result.Name.StartsWith("dt_")))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            info.SetValue(used, result.GetValue(results, null), null);
                        }
                        catch (NoNullAllowedException e)
                        {
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            dt_IRS.Rows.Add(makeRow(used, dt_IRS));
        }
```

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2017540/891715

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is if `schedule_end_date` or `schedule_start_date` is `null` your projection will *always* throw an exception because you attempt to call `ToString` on the property, regardless if it's assigned or not.

You need to do something like

```
schedule_end_date = result.schedule_end_date ?? DateTime.Parse("..."),
schedule_start_date = result.schedule_start_date ?? DateTime.Parse("...")
```

---

**Update**

Based on the revelation that `result.schedule_end_date`/`result.schedule_start_date` aren't actually nullable then you can't actually check whether the dates are `null` at all. Most likely, if the data is `null` at the DB end then *something* is translating the `null` to a valid `DateTime`.

Most ORMs will translate `null` to `DateTime.MinValue`.

---

Given you are using Linq to SQL you need to also set the `CanBeNull` property to `true` in the `Column` attribute i.e.

```
[Column(CanBeNull=true)]
public DateTime? schedule_start_date;

[Column(CanBeNull=true)]
public DateTime? schedule_end_date;
```

Then you can use the null-coalescing operator to set your default value i.e.

```
schedule_end_date = result.schedule_end_date ?? DateTime.ParseExact("yyyyMMdd", "99990101", CurrentCulture.InvariantCulture),
schedule_start_date = result.schedule_start_date ?? DateTime.ParseExact("yyyyMMdd", "99990101", CurrentCulture.InvariantCulture),
```

Comment: I tried schedule_end_date = result.schedule_end_date ?? DateTime.Parse("99990101"), however I get the error: "Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands System.DateTime and System.DateTime"

Comment: @vwdewaal so clearly `result.schedule_end_date` *isn't* a nullable date and therefore **cannot be null**. So really you don't need to check for `null` at all.

Comment: Yes, @James however the data coming from the SqlServer Database might be null, that I have no control over.  And therein lies the problem.

Comment: Also the  null-coalescing ?? will not compile.

Comment: Not really sure how you can get yourself in that situation though - are you manually mapping the information or are you using some sort of ORM? I would assume if the data in SQL is `null` then the date value is most likely going to be `DateTime.MinValue` - not `null`. Yes the null-coalescing won't work because `DateTime` can't ever be null, that's the point I was making in my first comment.

Comment: are you asking whether I'm responsible for the data in the SQL server database?  No, I'm not, I'm only reading from it.  And the value in the database is truly "null".  How they do it is beyond me.

Comment: @vwdewaal no I am simply pointing out the facts - a `DateTime` data type **cannot** be set to `null`. Therefore, regardless if the data is `null` at the DB end, when it comes to the client-side *something* is translating the `null` value to a valid `DateTime` value - most likely an ORM (if that's what you are using).

Comment: yes you are correct, I am using a sort of a ORM mapping `[Table(Name = "t_sdi_trading_book_product_interest_repricing_schedule_hsbc")]
    public class t_sdi_trading_book_product_interest_repricing_schedule_hsbc
    {
        [Column]
        public int sdi_control_id;
        [Column]
        public string account_deal_position_id;        
        [Column]
        public DateTime schedule_start_date;        
        [Column]
        public DateTime schedule_end_date;        
    }`

Comment: I have tried setting it to datetime? in here as well.  No joy

Comment: What ORM are you using? If those classes are auto-generated I would avoid touching them... It's best to do that sort of thing via the UI. To be honest I am still struggling to understand what your problem is? The fields are `DateTime` as is the class you are trying to map them to so what exactly is the issue? Are you getting an exception or compiler error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37534/discussion-between-vwdewaal-and-james)

Comment: Thanks for your help on this James.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
schedule_end_date = result.schedule_end_date ?? 
                    DateTime.Parse( // A valid string date );
```

Comment: I tried schedule_end_date = result.schedule_end_date ?? DateTime.Parse("99990101"), however I get the error: "Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands System.DateTime and System.DateTime"

Comment: "99990101" is not a valid DateTime string, use "9999-01-01"

Comment: I've tried 2099-01-01 or 9999-01-01 or 20990101, the error message stays the same (by error here I mean the whole  null-coalescing will not compile.

Comment: Can you give the exact error message you are getting (you can copy and paste it here if it is short enough). Then I will have a look.

Comment: This is it user65439 - The error that will not compile.  "Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands System.DateTime and System.DateTime"

Comment: You can also try to use schedule_end_date = result.schedule_end_date == null ? DateTime.Parse( // A valid string date ) : // Some valid date value;

Comment: Aha, this is because the type of your property is not set to DateTime? , which you said you cannot do. Did you try to use schedule_end_date = result.schedule_end_date == null ? DateTime.Parse("9999-01-01") : result.schedule_end_date;

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with using `nullable`. Simply change your `CreateDataTable` function to cope with it.

```
public class trading_book_product_IRS        
{
    public DataTable dt_IRS { get; set; }
    public string account_deal_position_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? schedule_start_date { get; set; }
    public DateTime? schedule_end_date { get; set; }
    public string repricing_type { get; set; }
    public string coupon_type { get; set; }
    public string reference_curve { get; set; }
    public string reference_curve_point { get; set; }
    public decimal interest_rate { get; set; }
    public decimal interest_rate_spread { get; set; }        
}

public static DataTable CreateDataTable(Type type)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    foreach (PropertyInfo info in type.GetProperties())
    {
        if(info.PropertyType == typeof(DataTable)) continue;

        DataColumn column;

        var type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(info.PropertyType);

        if(type != null)
        {
            column = new DataColumn(info.Name, type)
        }
        else
        {
            column = new DataColumn(info.Name, info.PropertyType);
        }

        dataTable.Columns.Add(column);
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

Inside the linq:

```
schedule_end_date = result.schedule_end_date
schedule_start_date = result.schedule_start_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work:

```
result.schedule_end_date == null ? result.schedule_end_date : DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900")
```

Comment: I don't have to .HasValue function available to me.  Not sure why.  I have also tried to say result.schedule_end_date == DateTime.Parse(result.schedule_end_date)

Answer (score -2):

Have you used

```
Nullable<DateTime>
```

**EDIT: I won't take this down, in my naivety I thought `Nullable<DateTime>` and `DateTime?` were different and were interpreted differently by the compiler. Turns out `DateTime?` Is shorthand for the previous version. Just a reference for anyone else that didn't know... I shall embrace the downvotes.**

Comment: He said he cannot use that.  And that syntax is completely backwards.

Comment: New Generic `DateTime` ?

Comment: My bad! A bit asleep today. I was under the impression that DateTime? and Nullable<DateTime> were different when interpreted by the compiler =s? I need to look this up

Comment: Nope, they're the same.

Comment: This is not an answer why this has to be **BOLD**?

Comment: Please read what I put. It's an edit to say I was wrong and here is why. It's merely a reference note for anyone else who didn't realise the link between Nullable<T> and appending a type with ?

It draws attention to the bold part as that is the important thing in what I wrote as opposed to my incorrect answer.