# How to retrieve data from database and set into the check-boxes

Tags: c#, sql-server, checkbox, load

I have a form in a c# application in which I am saving values from checkboxes to database. Now what I need to do is that to retrieve the saved values on same form for updating and editing purpose.

For example I have used this query to retrieve the data:

```
     "Select * from tblComplaints where ID = txtID.Text"
```

Here I want to know that How can I set the !null values on check-boxes?

Comment: Read up on parametrisation. A string won't replace the value of `"txtID.Txt"` with it's value and you should **never** inject it's values. Look up `Parameters.Add`

Comment: A like using a Data Grid View.  You can put data into a DataTable use the SQL Adapter and then make the Datatable the datasource : datagridview1.DataSource = dt.  Any Booleans in the database becomes a checkbox automatically.

Comment: @jdweng I don't want to use datagridview here. I just want to get data in checkboxes. If a column value is null then the check-box should not be checked and if the the column value has value then the check-box should be checked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to check if column returns a null value (from database to .net application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017533/best-way-to-check-if-column-returns-a-null-value-from-database-to-net-applicat/2017540)?